# Issue scraping products from table with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As may be obvious from below, I'm very new to selenium and python in general so please bear with me.

I am trying to scrape the product name, price and availability of products from the following website: https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Pokemon/Products/Boosters

I have located the table body element and made a list of all the different products within.  However, when I try to iterate through the list to extract the info, I get a no such element error AFTER extracting the info for the first product. As each product has the same class names for the info I do not understand why the first set of info can be located correctly but not the subsequent ones.

This is likely a silly mistake on my end but if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Code Below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Pokemon/Products/Boosters'
driver.get(url)

table_body = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value = 'table-body')
products = table_body.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='row.no-gutters')

for product in products:
    name = product.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="col-12.col-md-4.px-2.flex-column.align-items-start.justify-content-center")
    start_price = product.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="col-price.pr-sm-2")
    availability = product.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="col-availability.px-2")

    print(name.text, start_price.text, availability.text)
```

Output:

Brilliant Stars Booster 2,25 € 10527

### Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 37>()
     37 for product in products:
     38     name = product.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="col-12.col-md-4.px-2.flex-column.align-items-start.justify-content-center")
---> 39     start_price = product.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="col-price.pr-sm-2")
     40     availability = product.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="col-availability.px-2")
     42     print(name.text, start_price.text, availability.text)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/RPS_Env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:763, in WebElement.find_element(self, by, value)
    760     by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    761     value = '[name="%s"]' % value
--> 763 return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
    764                      {"using": by, "value": value})['value']

File ~/miniconda3/envs/RPS_Env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:740, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    738     params = {}
    739 params['id'] = self._id
--> 740 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/RPS_Env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:430, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    428 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    429 if response:
--> 430     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    431     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code. But if I may give you an advice, in this case, you dont need to use selenium, you can use requests and BeautifulSoup to get your data. it's easier and faster to use.

The requests lib offer you a way to get the html page without using an driver, and the BeautifulSoup parse the html page, making it very easy to get texts infos from the page.

try that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Pokemon/Products/Boosters'

req = requests.get(url) #make the request
bs = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser') #parse the data

#get all the elements in this path, in this case, Im geting the product name
product_names = bs.find_all(
    'div', {'col-12 col-md-4 px-2 flex-column align-items-start justify-content-center'})

for prod in  product_names:
    print(prod.text) #printing the result
```

Note the the same var 'bs' can be used to retrive all the info that you want from the page, you just need to locate the elements

Another thing, you probably want to retrive infos from multiple pages, in this case, you just need to figure out how to put you request inside a loop. In your exemple:

This is the page 2 of your research
https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Pokemon/Products/Boosters?site=2

This is the page 3:
https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Pokemon/Products/Boosters?site=3

only the last number has changed, so you can do something like that:

```
#to request 10 pages:
for i in range(10):
    url = 'https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Pokemon/Products/Boosters?site=' + str(i)
```

easy, right?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I'm doing this as part of an ed course so I need to use selenium. (I believe because it will become necessary for later parts of the project, though I'm not sure). However iterating through the multiple pages is definitely one of the next issues on my list so thanks for the advice on that